# Unable to access login container elements in chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using **PAYTM** site and click on the login button then a login container opened up .I tried to enter username and password but unable to proceed as am not able to access the elements.I tried window handler but it returns the same window id for main window and container window.

Site:- https://paytm.com/

I am using below code:-

```
driver.get("paytm.com");
String mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='login']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(uname);
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pwd);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
```

HTML Code:-

```
<input type="text" name="username" ng-class="{'number-new': ((sessionData.email | isMobile) &amp;&amp; loginForm.username.$dirty &amp;&amp; !loginForm.username.$error.required)}" ng-model="sessionData.email" data-required="" email-validate="" mobile-validate="" maxlength="30" data-ng-trim="false" class="ng-pristine md-input ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-parse ng-valid-mobile-valid ng-valid-email-valid ng-touched" tabindex="0" id="input_0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

Comment: Can you show  us a screenshot and HTML of both page?

Comment: May be it is in iFrame..

Comment: Yes it is an iframe and looks like there is many nested iframe present over the page

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: driver.get("https://paytm.com");
String mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='login']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(uname);
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pwd);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();

Comment: <input type="text" name="username" ng-class="{'number-new': ((sessionData.email | isMobile) &amp;&amp; loginForm.username.$dirty &amp;&amp; !loginForm.username.$error.required)}" ng-model="sessionData.email" data-required="" email-validate="" mobile-validate="" maxlength="30" data-ng-trim="false" class="ng-pristine md-input ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-parse ng-valid-mobile-valid ng-valid-email-valid ng-touched" tabindex="0" id="input_0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to iframe before finding username and password elements. See code below:

```
driver.get("https://paytm.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='login']")).click();
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[ng-hide='showVerificationScreen']")));         
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(uname); 
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pwd); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
```

P.S. You can determine if your element is in iframe or not by using Chrome devtool, firebug, or others. The screenshot shows that username element is inside an iframe.
[image: Username element is inside an iframe]

Comment: got it now.thanks very much. and i have small doubt that i could see only a form tag but not iframe tag then why we use switch to iframe there?

Comment: I've added the screenshot of Chrome's devtool in my answer. You can see that the element username is inside an iframe.

Comment: cool buaban ... You have show me a new way today to identify that if the element is in iframe or not.. Already upvoted :) ... @Sreejith -- please accept the Buaban answer if it really helps you :)

Comment: Intially, I have tried with same on using xpath ng-hide='showVerificationScreen' with xpath .. it was not working but it is working with css .. do you know why buaban?

Comment: @ShubhamJain It works fine on my machine. Could you try this? `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@ng-hide='showVerificationScreen']")));`

Comment: nup it still not working for me using xpath ... Can using crome dev tools we can identify nested frames also?

Comment: @ShubhamJain Yes, it can show nested frames. But if your iframe has id, it will show that id instead of tag name.

Comment: Thanks Buaban.. so if the iframe have an id then in crome dev tool it will show the id instead of frame. right? . like here in above example as you show frame is showing on dev tool but suppose if this iframe has an id then instead of frame it will show id

Comment: @ShubhamJain sorry, I forgot to mention that when it shows id, you can click on the id and it will show both tag name and id.

Comment: On HTML DOM .. right? .. when I click on the id then it will show me the frame tag on HTML DOM respectively .. right?