# Unable to locate a visible element with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I would like to click on a calendar entry in this [site](https://hornblowernewyork.com/cruises/international-sightseeing-cruise/) using selenium in python. Although I can clearly see each calendar entry and I can get its xpath, id etc. But when I try to locate the element I get an errror.
(For example, I can see that the link for the 20th day of April has an id='20160420')

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
el=browser.find_element_by_id('20160420')
```

Any suggestions (I tried switching between frames, active elements etc. but to no avail so far ...)

Comment: Are you sure you switched to correct iframe?

Comment: I am not quite sure. I saw two frames in the code and tried switching to both. Is there a way to list all frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your code didn't switch to iframe yet. See example code below:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
time.sleep(5)
iframe = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#crowdTorchTicketingMainContainer > iframe')
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
el=browser.find_element_by_id('20160420')
print(el.text)
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks! Quick follow up - how did you find the css selector for the correct frame. I tried searching for this frame in the raw page source but nothing came up

Comment: You can use Chrome Dev'Tool to see hierarchy of elements. See my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194819/unable-to-access-login-container-elements-in-chrome/35196463?noredirect=1#comment58112245_35196463.
Regarding the Css Selector expression, I created it by myself. You can see some interesting examples from https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the element that you are looking for is in an iframe, and you have to switch to that before you can access the calendar element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as WDW
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException,     TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException


url = 'https://hornblowernewyork.com/cruises/international-sightseeing-cruise'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)

# seach for the appropriate iframe
frame = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#crowdTorchTicketingMainContainer > iframe")
if not frame:
  raise Exception('Frame not found')

# once the correct iframe is found switch to it, 
# then look for your calendar element
browser.switch_to.frame(frame)
try:
  el = WDW(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "20160406"))
  )
except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException), e:
  print e
else:
  print el
```

Comment: I think it would be better if we use css selector to get the iframe directly. For instance, frame = find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[src*='ticketmob']")

Comment: based on your comments @Buaban, I changed my answer to search for just one iframe by css selector, rather than sorting through a group filtering by attributes within the iframes.